# Magento 2 - Send all communication emails to secondary email

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have created a new customer attribute to store customer secondary/communication email address details.

I want to send all kind of emails to only secondary/communication email address.

**Which is the best way to achieve this ??**

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: What if customer not filling the secondary email address.?

Comment: @ArpitJain, Then i have to use primary email address. My first preference is to send all communication emails to secondary email address.

Comment: Did you check that how mail is going to the primary one you just have to create a template for that

Comment: @ArpitJain Yes, i am doing it. As of now my plan is to use plugins (I know this will take some extra time to develop). I thought to check is there any other way (better, simple and fastest way).

Comment: Yes there is a way but for that you have to create a module and that is not a easy way to do that so using a plugin is a good choice if you dont have a time.

Comment: @ArpitJain What is that ? can you explain more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207161/discussion-between-naresh-and-arpit-jain).